# VBA excel column header

Tags: vba, excel

I have ton of excel files that I am merging into 1 excel file and I need to put the column name or header on the first row. I have 3 columns: customerid, date, prediction. How do I put the column name on cell A1, B1, and C1 in VBA code? Thanks.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("directory\path")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A2:C" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You only want the column in A, B and C, even though you copy columns A to IV of each workbook?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, just want column A1, B1, and C1. I just changed the code range to A2:C

Comment: Ummmm... `Range("A1").Value = "customerid"`, etc?

Comment: @Comintern that made me laugh +1 - sharp - Macro recorder is your best friend!

Comment: `Thisworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1:c1") = bookList.Worksheets("Sheet name or index").Range("a1:c1")`

Comment: @Kyle Thanks it works. New to VBA

Comment: One more for the pot: `.cells(1, 1).resize(1, 3) = array("customerid", "date", "prediction")`

Comment: @sharp Glad I could help. We've all been there before.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for an even easier way:`[A1:C1] = Split("customerid date prediction")`

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub whatever()
    Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("customerid", "date", "prediction")
End Sub
```